# Is it the right choice to open/close a text file for writing each 0.01 sec?

Tags: c, loops, fopen, fclose

I have to collect data through an accelerometer, perform some computations and append the result into a text file (in a MicroSD card connected via SPI). The code is working, but I should increase the speed to a log each 0.01 seconds. Is it healthy for the MicroSD to open/close at this speed?

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "SDFileSystem.h"

SDFileSystem sd (SPI_MOSI_SD, SPI_MISO_SD, SPI_SCK_SD, SPI_SS_SD, "sd");

int main (void)
{
  mkdir("/sd/data", 0777);
  while (1)
  {
    // record from accelerometer and perform calculations
    FILE *fp = fopen("/sd/data/parameters.txt", "a");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
      error("Could not open file for write.\n");
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%.4f\n", parameter);
    fclose(fp);
    wait_ms(100);
  }
}
```

My problem is that the while loop never ends: I have to write data continuously and decide to interrupt only by switching off the device. In this way fclose(fp) never happens.

Comment: open only once keep the handle and close it once you are done writing that is after `while` loop if you are so much concerned about `open/close`.

Comment: Notice that the programming language seems to be C++!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my day SD cards typically wrote their data as full sectors even if you were writing one byte. I'm assuming that's still the case so doing it your way would wear a sector many times over without needing to do so. That's why buffering is important. The data should be buffered at around 512 bytes (typical sector size).Build up the buffer until it reaches 512 bytes then flush by writing to SD card.

```
char sd_buffer[512];
unsigned short buffer_idx = 0;
:
void append_buffer ( char *str )
{
   while ( *str )
   {
       sd_buffer[buffer_idx++] = *str++;

       if ( buffer_idx >= 512 )
       {
            FILE *fp = fopen("/sd/data/parameters.txt", "a");
            if ( fp == NULL )
                  return; // error
            // flush buffer
            fwrite(sd_buffer,1,512,fp);
            fclose(fp);
            buffer_idx = 0;
       }
   }
}
:
while (1) 
{
    char buf[32];
    sprintf(buf,"%.4f\n", parameter);
    append_buffer(sd_buffer,buf);
    wait_ms(100);
}
```

This just means it will be writing less to the SD card (at each 512 byte interval)

*Disclaimer: untested*

Ps. The open/close the file is now in `append_buffer` such that any file system buffers are also flushed.

If you are having problems with loops. Use a [state machine](https://aticleworld.com/state-machine-using-c/)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it healthy for the MicroSD to open/close at this speed?

It's writing that wears it. I cannot see why opening and closing should matter. But it's totally unnecessary to do like you do. Do like this instead:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/sd/data/parameters.txt", "a");

if(fp == NULL) {
    error("Could not open file for write.\n");
}

while (1) {
    fprintf(fp, "%.4f\n", parameter);
    // If your worry is that the file buffer won't be written to disk
    // in case of a power off, just flush the stream.
    fflush(fp);
    wait_ms(100);
}

fclose(fp);
```

But of course, it's good practice to check the return value for both `fprintf` and `fflush` to detect errors.

> My problem is that the while loop never ends: I have to write data continuously and decide to interrupt only by switching off the device. In this way fclose(fp) never happens.

It sounds like what you need is a [Journaling file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system)

Comment: My problem is that the while loop never ends: I have to write data continuously and decide to interrupt only by switching off the device. In this way fclose(fp) never happens.

Comment: @SaidQuqa And this is why you should *describe the problem you have* in the question. This is an [XY-problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Besides, if you're doing this every 0.01s, the probability that the file will be open when you shut off is not negligible.

Comment: sorry, I used the loop "while" because of this

Comment: If you added `fflush(fp)` in the while loop you shouldn't have to worry about not getting to the`fclose()`.

Comment: @PhilipKearns I was writing about that when you commented :)

Answer (score 2):

You can buffer the data when you think that open/close isn´t fast enough.
Just collect 100 or more datapoints from your acc and write them back at once every second for example.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that the while loop never ends: I have to write data continuously and decide to interrupt only by switching off the device. In this way fclose(fp) never happens.

In the case described above, adding a `fclose` every 100 ms still will not help you. You might loose the last written data if the shutdown happens during the write.

1. If you are OK, with possibly loosing the last write, then

   - The buffered write will anyway happen at the end of line character `\n`
   - So you can close the file at the end of main, (or not at all)
2. If you want to always have the write in the SD card even on shutdown the design is more complicated. You will need -

   - to detect the power off. You can use an ADC channel.
   - A capacitor on the power supply which will keep power on to the controller for some time (maybe 50ms)
   - A shutdown routine which will run on power off which will ensure that the buffered write is completed and close the file.